# JS Array Not Displaying Properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, push

This was my attempt at writing a loop that loops through nums, if the item is even, it adds it to the evens array, if the item is odd, it adds it to the odds array.

```
    var nums = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];
var evens = [];
var odds = [];

var sorter = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]%2 !== 0) {
            odds.push(i);
        }
        else {
            evens.push(i);
        }
    }
};
sorter();
console.log(evens);
console.log(odds);
```

Comment: Welcome to to SO! It seems to me that your question is not clear to me. Would you please clarify what you are after?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are pushing your iterator to the arrays. You should do this:

```
var nums = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];
var evens = [];
var odds = [];

var sorter = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]%2 !== 0) {
            odds.push(nums[i]);
        }
        else {
            evens.push(nums[i]);
        }
    }
};
sorter();
console.log(evens);
console.log(odds);
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/33h51pty/)